# Where does the Shulchan Aruch quote an authority by name?

Tags: shulchan-aruch

Generally speaking, R' Yosef Karo doesn't quote authorities by name in his Shulchan Aruch, but rather focuses on what the halacha is in the Shulchan Aruch and leaves the various opinions and rationales to be explained in his Beis Yosef.

In going through Hilchos Pesach, I stumbled upon the first exception I've seen to this, in [OC 460:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.460.2) (translation is Sefaria's):

> הרא"ש היה משתדל במצת מצוה ועומד על עשיית' ומזרז העוסקים ומסייע בהן בעריכתן
>
> The R"ASH would personally deliberate on the Matzot Mitzvah and oversee the production, inspire those working and assisting them in the flattening [of the dough].

Is this unique in the Shulchan Aruch, or are there other places where he refers to an authority by name?

Comment: I’d imagine opinions are cited by tefilin

Comment: There are dozens of such examples

Comment: In general, do you imply Hamechaber had a systematic approach to writing S"A - like mentioning some and ignoring others?

Comment: Related (just posted) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101696/what-rules-did-hamachaber-set-to-himself-before-compiling-the-shulchan-aruch

Answer (score 8):

It's actually not that rare for the Shulchan Aruch to mention authorities by name. Here are a bunch of examples of different authorities mentioned:

In [O.C. 34:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x398) he mentions  a dispute involving Rashi, Rambam, and Rabbeinu Tam:

> סדר הנחתן בבתיםלרש"י והרמב"ם קדש משמאל המניח בבית החיצון ואחריו כי יביאך בבית שני ושמע בבית השלישי והיה אם שמוע  בבית הרביעי שהוא בית החיצון ב לימינו ולר"ת בבית השלישי והיה אם שמוע ובבית הרביעי שהוא החיצון שמע ומנהג העולם כרש"י והרמב"ם

In [O.C. 185:5](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1004) he mentions an uncertainty that Tosafos and the Rosh had:

> ואם בירך והיתה צואה כנגדו או שהיה שכור (פי' לגמרי) נסתפקו התוספות והרא"ש אם צריך לחזור ולברך ומשום מי רגלים פשיטא שאינו חוזר לברך

In [O.C. 320:14](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1579) he mentions a dispute between R. Meir of Rothenberg and the Rosh:

> הר"מ מרוטנבורג מתיר להטיל מי רגלים בשלג והרא"ש היה נזהר

[O.C. 591:6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2959) he mentions that the Ran and the Rosh defended a custom:

> והרא"ש והר"ן כתבו לקיים המנהג

There are many other examples of this, some where multiple authorities are listed together or contrasted, and some where only one authority is cited.

Answer (score 5):

[Here's](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.308.50?with=all&lang=bi) a double naming in hilchos muktza:

> הרשב"א מתיר לטלטל האיצטרלו"ב בשבת וכן ספרי החכמה ולדעת הרמב"ם יש להסתפק בדבר:

Comment: This one always stands out in my mind as the basis of the machlokes is arguably not in line with what we would say is each rabbi's philosophy about science.

Comment: First thing to pop on my mind

Comment: There are dozens of such examples. The important thing to say in an answer is that it happens dozens of times. An example is helpful but not the primary info requested

Comment: @Double it's true there are many. I'm not sure based on his language what his primary goal was.