# What rules did Hamechaber set to himself before compiling the Shulchan Aruch?

Tags: halacha-theory, shulchan-aruch

Following [Doniel's question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101684/where-else-does-the-shulchan-aruch-quote-an-authority-by-name), did R' Yosef Karo accept himself a set of fixed rules/guidelines by which he is going to compile the Shulchan Aruch?

For example, the order of Halochos, what he brings and what he omits from Tur, what authorities does he mention and what he doesn't, where he brings a Machlokes and where he Paskens.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94186/what-does-it-mean-halachicly-hamechaber-omitted-those-halochos

Comment: Did you read his introduction? It's not that long. See what he says himself

Answer (score 4):

Hakdamat Bet Yosef

> ולכן הסכמתי בדעתי כי להיות שלשה עמודי ההוראה אשר הבית בית ישראל נשען עליהם בהוראותיהם הלא המה הרי''ף הרמב''ם והרא''ש ז''ל אמרתי אל לבי כי במקום ששנים מהם מסכימים לדעת אחת נפסוק הלכה כמותם אם לא במקצת מקומות שכל חכמי ישראל או רובם חולקין על הדעת ההוא ולכן פשט המנהג ההיפך

Bet Yosef rules Halacha as both of the set Rif, Rambam, Rosh. An exception: When all or the majority of chachme Israel rule differently and the custom spreaded as their opinion.

For detailed additional principles and rules in the Bet Yosef way see  [Sefer Yad Malachi](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14122&st=&pgnum=412&hilite=.)

Comment: THank you. THis explains the majority of his Halachic rulings. How about the rest - HOW he wrote the S"A, when he elaborates, when he omits etc.

Comment: I don't know. There is a sefer called Yad Malachi who details the klale hamechaber

Comment: Done I added Link..

Comment: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shulchan_Aruch#Beit_Yosef

Comment: For what it's worth, when you look at the actual contents, the SA violates this general rule pretty often.

Comment: @MichaBerger THat's exactly the point of my investigation - whether the Rabbis approach the Halacha systematically or just roll as it goes. Somehow I arrived at a negative conclusion.